# Hadoop on MAC pseudo node : nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: hadoop

I am a Hadoop newbie. I installed Hadoop on my MAC using this [link](http://importantfish.com/how-to-run-hadoop-in-standalone-mode-using-eclipse-on-mac-os-x/)

It worked like a charm for me to begin with, but now I hit this problem when I run the same WordCount problem from Eclipse :

```
ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:<username> cause:java.net.UnknownHostException: <hostname>: <hostname>: hostname nor servname provided, or not known
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: <hostname>: <hostname>: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:960)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:57)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: <hostname>: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
```

This is how my conf files look :

*core-site.xml:*

```
<configuration>

<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

---

*hadoop-env.sh*

Has the following entry, in addition the defaults:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.realm=OX.AC.UK -Djava.security.krb5.kdc=kdc0.ox.ac.uk:kdc1.ox.ac.uk"
```

---

*hdfs-site.xml*

```
<configuration>

<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

---

*mapred-site.xml*

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:9001</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

---

I also see this in the beginning of the errors:

```
2013-10-11 21:03:08.795 java[7484:1903] Unable to load realm mapping info from SCDynamicStore
13/10/11 21:03:08 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/10/11 21:03:08 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/10/11 21:03:08 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
13/10/11 21:03:08 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-<uname>/mapred/staging/<uname>386844365/.staging/job_local386844365_0001
```

Can somebody please tell me if I am doing anything wrong ? My program is the same and havent changed the defaults (which used to work)

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem was with the host file. Fixed it by adding this to the /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
127.0.1.1   <hostname>
```

Answer (score 24):

You can fix this with a simple command:

```
echo "127.0.0.1 $HOSTNAME" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

([Source](https://coderwall.com/p/ktbkea/play-framework-2-error-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known))

Comment: Be careful with this command. Depending on your shell and/or environment $HOSTNAME may not be available. It will be ok for bash, not for zsh.

Comment: Thanks for citing the source too.

Answer (score 0):

On my MAC, it turns out to be DNS provided by ISP was polluted or wrong at that time. Set system DNS to 8.8.8.8 (primary DNS server for Google DNS) or other public DNS fixed my problem.